# How to change a point of an arrow on Print Composer?

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, print-composer, qgis-2.12

To create an arrow on the Print Composer I've used this:

`qC = QgsComposition(iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer())
arw = QgsComposerArrow(QPointF(0, 0),QPointF(10,10),qC)`

However, I can't find an attribute or method to change any of the two points.

I've tried with:

`arw.setRect(QRectF(QPointF(0,0),QPointF(0,20)))`

but it seems to change the precision and swaps the arrow head to the other end with every change. The same happens using `.setSceneRect()` . It seems to me this is not the way to go. Can anybody help me with this?